# Creating layer showing difference between two shapefiles using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, geoprocessing

I have 2 zoning shapefiles for different years. I am creating a swipe map that will show those two years separately to visualize change in zoning. In addition to this, I want to create a third map that shows the difference between them.

Which tool or which approach would accomplish this analysis?

Answer (score 3):

Symmetrical Difference is likely the best tool for your application (though it does required an Advanced license).

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/symmetrical-difference.htm

> Features or portions of features in the input and update features that
> do not overlap will be written to the output feature class.
>
> [image: Symmetrical Difference Illustration]